# what is master page using html-php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, master-pages

I have been working on a website which is much similar to [olx](http://www.olx.in/). It will display ads depending upon the location of visitor (eg if i am from mumbai then it should display ads of mumbai only). I was following a traditional way but in this way I will have to create too many pages 
(even if I consider major cities only). Then I got a suggestion to create a master page which will make task a lot easier.

But I am yet to understand concept of master page in my case. While trying to understand I have been to few web pages like [Master Pages using HTML and JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114458/Master-Pages-using-HTML-and-JavaScript) . But it looks this concept is used to create consistent look and behavior.

Can anyone tell me how I can implement it?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

You define the static parts of the websites such as the header, sidebar and footer and then stick each of those pieces into different files. You then use a server side language such as PHP to include those files into the returned view. It allows you to modify one file and then that change will be reflected throughout the all of the pages that include the resource.

Answer (score 1):

The way olx handle ads are based on the ip address of the user visting the webpage, lets say `xxx.xx.xx.xxx` belongs to mumbai then they filter the ads of mumbai from their database and show it up . its all based on the Geolocation  and they also  used `.htaccess` to create subdomain say `mumbai.olx.in`

Answer (score 0):

You should define blocks in your page. Dynamic blocks should be filled based upon some situations i.e. in your case users of Mumbai.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement that concept using the `[include_once][1]` function from PHP, which allows you to insert more files in one file. For example if you have:

File: `header.php`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
</head>
<body>
```

File `footer.php`

```
<p>This is footer</p>
</body>
</html>
```

File:`index.php`

```
<?php include_once 'header.php';?>
<h1>Hello world! </h1>
<?php include_once 'footer.php';?>
```

Hope that helps you !